# Android Splashscreen Logo

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

I have an project written in Kotlin.

My app has adaptive launcher icon, legacy squared and legacy round icon in files.

My launcher icons have `.png` background just because it has gradient.

Icons work fine, but in built in splashscreen the app displays icon, which does not mix well with splashscreen's background color.

My question is - can i alter the built-in splashscreen to make it use only `ic_launcher_foreground` while displaying splashscreen instead the whole `ic_launcher` without changing the app icon itself ( including changing the `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` in manifest file )

Cheers.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on splash screens](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen)? You can specify the icon drawable. It doesn't have to match what you're using for the launcher activity or application. Since you have an adaptive icon, you can specify only the foreground drawable as your splash screen icon.